# Search for string and replace with another

Tags: r

I have data with one of the column as

```
         Activity Description             
   --------------------------------------------- 
       Handling &  PNR Movement Charges-FCL        
       Value Added Charges                         
       Container Tracking Charges-FCL              
       Contrainer Ground Rent Charges-FCL          
       Documentation Charges FCL                   
       Insurance Charges-FCL                       
       Seal Charges                                
       Fuel Charges-FCL                            
       Container Movement and Increase Charges-FCL 
       Weighment Charges-FCL                       
       Container Movement and Increase Charges-FCL
```

I need to search for string which contains "FCL" and replace the word without FCL.
Ex. Insurance charges-FCL to Insurance charges i.e I dont need the string FCL.

I tried with below code,

```
 for (line in file_read$`Activity Description`){
 if (line == "*FCL"){
 new_column <- c(new_column,"*")
```

It is not working.

Is my code right or I need to change with another script of code?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `sub("FCL", "", file_read$Activity Description)`

Comment: Can you show a larger data set?  Does `FCL` always occur at the end of the string, preceded by a dash?

Comment: Thanks it works.

Comment: Does that really work?  Wouldn't it leave behind dashes in your names?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, It prints with dashes, but how can I remove the dashes, but string has dashes and another string doesn't

Comment: Please answer my earlier comment.  Show sample data which covers _all_ the types of descriptions where `FCL` can appear.  Then, someone can give you a more exact answer.

Comment: It can appear only at end with spaces or dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `FCL` would always occur at the *end* of your descriptions, preceded by a dash, space, or some other non alphanumeric character, then here is a safe way to do the replacement using `sub`:

```
df$`Activity Description` <- sub("[^[:alnum:]]FCL$", "", df$`Activity Description`)
```

Comment: Thanks It is working, but how can remove the dashes if dashes present with string named FCL?

Comment: This would replace `-FCL` with empty string.  Not sure what you are asking.  For the third time, please update your question with complete sample data.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I didnt properly check.